# What is the reason for the difference in melting point between oleic acid (9-octadecenoic acid) and isooleic acid (10-octadecenoic acid)

Tags: bond

Isooleic acid only differs from oleic acid in the position of the double bond. I don't understand why this might lead to an increase in the melting point. The degree of saturation hasn't changed and nor has the length of the carbon chain.

Comment: Ask yourself the different way - why should the change of both chains at the double bond have no influence? 1-butene has m.p. -185.3 Deg C,  and 2-butene -138.9 deg C, both the same chain length and double bond count.

Comment: What is this difference, then? I found so far only m.p. for trans isomer of your isooleic acid.

Comment: Another issue is that it could have polymorphs with different m.p.

Comment: https://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0108270191012921

Comment: Oleic acid is not just 9-octadecneoic acid it is (Z)-9-Octadecenoic acid (cis at the double bond). isooleic acid is usually (E)-10-Octadecenoic acid (trans at the double bond). are those the two compounds you are comparing? If so, do you see an obvious major difference?